# Requests take long time in apache reverse proxy having multiple backends

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, vhosts

I am using Apache 2.2.34 as a reverse proxy server. There are more than 10 backends. At a given time, only *one backend server works* and they all work/enabled in a round-robin fashion.
vhost configuration is similar to following.

```
<Proxy balancer://AWSELB>
BalancerMember https://backendEC2_1:443/ retry=60
BalancerMember https://backendEC2_2:443/ retry=60
BalancerMember https://backendEC2_3:443/ retry=60
BalancerMember https://backendEC2_4:443/ retry=60
BalancerMember https://backendEC2_5:443/ retry=60
BalancerMember https://backendEC2_6:443/ retry=60
BalancerMember https://backendEC2_7:443/ retry=60
BalancerMember https://backendEC2_8:443/ retry=60
BalancerMember https://backendEC2_9:443/ retry=60
BalancerMember https://backendEC2_10:443/ retry=60    
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / balancer://AWSELB/ forcerecovery=Off timeout=5
ProxyPassReverse / https://backendEC2_1:443/
ProxyPassReverse / https://backendEC2_2:443/
ProxyPassReverse / https://backendEC2_3:443/
ProxyPassReverse / https://backendEC2_4:443/
ProxyPassReverse / https://backendEC2_5:443/
ProxyPassReverse / https://backendEC2_6:443/
ProxyPassReverse / https://backendEC2_7:443/
ProxyPassReverse / https://backendEC2_8:443/
ProxyPassReverse / https://backendEC2_9:443/
ProxyPassReverse / https://backendEC2_10:443/
```

Currently I have set above parameters in virtual worker and used retry parameter. With these setting, a request is severed but most of times it takes up to 15 minutes to serve a page.
What would be the best vhost configuration for the given scenario?

Comment: How often does the active backend node change?

Comment: We dont have control over when the backend will change.

Comment: Can you maybe upgrade to latest Apache? Than you could use [mod_proxy_hcheck](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_hcheck.html)

Comment: Yes, this module will serve my purpose but we cant update our Apache major version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following config worked for me.

```
<Proxy balancer://AWSELB>
BalancerMember https://backendEC2_1:443 connectiontimeout=1
BalancerMember https://backendEC2_2:443 connectiontimeout=1
BalancerMember https://backendEC2_3:443 connectiontimeout=1
BalancerMember https://backendEC2_4:443 connectiontimeout=1
BalancerMember https://backendEC2_5:443 connectiontimeout=1
BalancerMember https://backendEC2_6:443 connectiontimeout=1
BalancerMember https://backendEC2_7:443 connectiontimeout=1
BalancerMember https://backendEC2_8:443 connectiontimeout=1
BalancerMember https://backendEC2_9:443 connectiontimeout=1
BalancerMember https://backendEC2_10:443 connectiontimeout=1
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / balancer://AWSELB/
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://AWSELB/
```

With **connectiontimeout** parameter if connection is not made to backend in 1 second then next worker is selected and so on, until a healhty worker is found.

Note that settings like maxattempt, timeout will have default values as described in [Apache 2.2 docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass)